# Another collatz tree

Tags: modular-arithmetic, fractals, collatz-conjecture

Here's a collatz tree that i drew.[image]

It contains the powers of two along its backbone, and $(2^n-1)/3$ where possible. Those numbers themselves have each a backbone of their own with $(2^nk-1)/3$ where possible. Note that odd numbers do not have branches since we do not apply $3n+1$ to even numbers. The backbones highlighted in green are 'dead'. They are divisible by 3 so no vertex can have an integer $(2^nk-1)/3$. (I made a mistake though, 53 is not meant to be highlighted).

The collatz conjecture claims that every number is contained within this tree and that the only cycled or repeated number is $1$ which is labelled R in a circle and is branching from $2^2$. Anyway, my question is how do you explain or express the regularity of this 'fractal'? This includes the fact that the 'multiplier' leading to branches at every backbone is either two or four and each new branch is separated by $2^2$. Also is there a regularity in where the green backbones pop up? I imagine it can be shown through modular arithmetic.

It was a pain drawing this. I am open to any suggestions on computational methods, i.e. a fractal generator or something in order to make it look clearer.

Comment: You might possibly interested in my attempts to give that tree a nice graphical expression. See http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/aboutloop/collloopintro_main.htm and at this page the subpage on "numerical and graphical trees" . I thought a "bottle-brush" might perhaps be the best analog-world scheme for your version of a "fractal" tree...

Answer (score 3):

In a compressed format (omitting the even numbers) an approach to draw that tree (in Excel) is this one:

[image: picture]

The blocks of numbers are meant as infinite to the right side. The numbers, read downwards in the columns and then horizontal across the columns are in a sequence $a_{k+1}=4 a_k+1$ and the colored arrows show the dependance of child-boxes to parent-entries. For instance, the red arrow from the $17$-box to its parent $13$ means $17=(13 \cdot 4-1)/3$ where the multiplier is $4$ and the green arrow from the box $227$ to its parent $341$ means $227 = (341 \cdot 2-1)/3$ where the multiplier is $2$.

It can surely be optimized, though..., perhaps I come back to this, later.

Comment: am i wrong in thinking that this could turn out to look like a decent looking fractal?

Comment: @Dis-integrating: No, I think that has some true fractal structure... Note that in this example all odd positive integer seem to be leaves of a tree "based" on one single "root". But if we look in the negative we have (at least) three such roots; $-1$, then a cycling pair $-5,-7$ as root (I like to say "nest" as with the birds instead) and another "nest" having $-17$ in its cycle/"nest". So there (at least) three of such trees being *intertwined*. Similarly for the $5x+1$ and other problem-variants...

Comment: It would be interesting if we could find an easy way of describing the fractal of any problem variant, (i.e. kn+1) without having to draw it out. For example, as your diagram as concisely shown we see that the numbers on each branch modulo 3 increase by one. So the overall pattern is quite clear. for the problem variant $5x+1$ it's clear that we separate branches by 2^4 but taking the modulus 5 is not so regular.

Comment: @Dis-integrating - I'm just working on the detection of the pattern for the $3x+1$,$5x+1$,$7x+1$, etc cases and the scheme is finally not very complex. I just do not yet see how this can be made really useful...

Comment: oh right ok. I was mainly interested in what causes the pattern at a fundamental level